# how to connect data base with EJB entity bean

Tags: mysql, ejb, entity-bean

how to configure EJB with mysql. where will put username,password , driver class etc...

i want access one table using EJB entity bean , it is installed in my local computer.  how it is possble..

**thanks and regards.....**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll suggest the following:

1. Use JPA to manage your database layer. 
   You can use [Eclipselink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)  or [hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) to implement JPA.
2. Create connection pool
3. Inject EntityManager in Session bean
4. From here you are ready to access database

Hope that helps to kickstart.

Sorry typing on phone so can't explain in detail.

Comment: wondering why there are no "mobility" badges on stackoverflow :)